# Android application with phonegap using html5 javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm building android application with the help of phonegap (I'm using html5 and javascript).
The two questions I have are as follows:

1. I'm not able to complete instagram integration step 3 to access token from url. Can anyone help as I want to use javascript code for the actions above?
2. My application has feature to upload pictures but that should be done using instagram application. So how to invoke or redirect to already existing instagram application on clicking the camera image?

Do reply soon!

Comment: Step 3 is to retrieve the access token from url after authorizing 3rd party app, and send it again as post.

Comment: how to use instagram intent any clue?????????????

Comment: Finally agreed that can be done only by PHP :(